# How to configure shared library search path after building GCC on my own?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I just built GCC 5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, which has gcc 4.8 as default. When I try to build things with it, I find that `ld` will use the default libstdc++ instead of the newly build one.

Here is the output:

```
drizzlex@dx ~/test
$ g++ hello.cpp 

drizzlex@dx ~/test
$ ldd a.out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffde0d25000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6     (0x00007fa181ad2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa1817cc000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa1815b5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa1811f0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa181dfd000)
```

And if I use `$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/`, it will find the right one.

```
drizzlex@dx ~/test
$ ldd a.out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffeeaf5000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4583d92000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4583a67000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4583850000)    
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f458348b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f458410e000)
```

I would like to know what should I do to make it correct? Since I know set LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not the best choice.

Comment: Under /etc/ld.so.conf.d/, there are some conf files which belong to the default gcc, should I write one by myself for my gcc 5.1? Or should I edit the existing ones? Or what?

Comment: Where did you install gcc-5.1? I mean the `--prefix` option.

Comment: Why is LD_LIBRARY_PATH not the best choice? Anyway, you should also make sure to point to the updated include path (e.g by setting CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH)

Comment: You can add a new file `/etc/ld.conf.d/gcc-5.1.conf` with `/usr/local/lib64` of course, and then run `ldconfig`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For building with g++ 5.1 use this:

```
$ g++5.1 hello.cpp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib64
```

And you will not need set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

This is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath

> rpath is a term in programming which refers to a run-time search path
>   hard-coded in an executable file or library, used during dynamic
>   linking to find the libraries the executable or library requires.

Comment: I find that libc is separate from gcc but libstdc++ is not? Because I find that  there are two libstdc++, libstdc++.so.6.0.19 and libstdc++.so.6.0.21, I think they come with gcc 4.8 and 5.1 respectively. However, I think there is just one libc, that is /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6.

Comment: Yes, libc is separate from gcc and for example on Linux libc installed with OS. libstdc++ comes with g++ and it is part of it: - https://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/